# bitcoin-qt (master branch) shutdown delay on debian stretch

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-qt-setup

Following a bitcoin core [issue](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50125/failing-to-build-bitcoin-core-v0-13-1-on-debian-stretch) on `debian stretch` which was resolved on the master branch, I am now running a pre-release test build. Each time I exit `bitcoin-qt`, I have to wait about 5 minutes until final shutdown occurs. My debug file is showing:

```
2016-12-20 19:58:55 AcceptToMemoryPool: peer=3: accepted 2b8c3...5c14 (poolsz ...
2016-12-20 19:58:56 AcceptToMemoryPool: peer=3: accepted 4a3d1...7e0e (poolsz ...
2016-12-20 19:58:56 tor: Thread interrupt
2016-12-20 19:58:56 scheduler thread interrupt
2016-12-20 19:58:56 torcontrol thread exit
2016-12-20 19:58:56 opencon thread interrupt
2016-12-20 19:58:56 addcon thread interrupt
2016-12-20 19:58:56 msghand thread interrupt
2016-12-20 19:58:56 net thread interrupt
```

This is where it hangs for a few minutes, then:

```
2016-12-20 20:05:58 Imported mempool transactions from disk: 10932 successes, 476 failed, 0 expired
2016-12-20 20:05:58 Shutdown: In progress...
2016-12-20 20:05:58 Stop
2016-12-20 20:05:59 Erased 1 orphan tx from peer 5
2016-12-20 20:06:01 Dumped mempool: 0.063746s to copy, 1.55051s to dump
2016-12-20 20:06:01 Shutdown: done
```

I have not experienced this before ever on any system. I am not seeing a similar issue when shutting down `bitcoind` (**EDIT** actually it does happen with `bitcoind` at times). **I am wondering if anyone is aware of any pending change (on master branch for future release) which would explain such behavior** (I worry this may be related to `debian stretch`, but my hardware is new, very cheap and hopelessly slow on known benchmarks, which may also be the cause of this).

Comment: Please report this as a bug.